# Django - How to decrease page load times? Getting list of 1000 objects and using page pagination

Tags: django, view, pagination

In my django project, one of my pages, `components.html` is taking around 7-8 seconds to load. In my `components_view` view I do calls to get all objects (total count is less than 2,000) and then use page pagination to to only display 12 components on a single page, however it's still taking 7-8 seconds to load the page...

How can I decrease load times for this page in particular - I thought page pagination would've solved this issue. Can I preload the data when the user accesses the home page? Server is a paid heroku server.

**views.py**

```
def components_view(request):
    # get objects from models
    subsystems          = Subsystem.objects.all()
    subsystems          = subsystems.order_by('name')
    component_types     = ComponentType.objects.all()
    components          = Component.objects.all()  # gets around 1500 objects
    form_factors        = FormFactor.objects.all()
    vendors             = Vendor.objects.order_by('name').all()  # gets 300 objects
    
    # page pagination
    COMPONENTS_PER_PAGE = 12
    component_paginator = Paginator(components, COMPONENTS_PER_PAGE)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_components = component_paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
        'subsystems': subsystems, 
        'component_types': component_types, 
        'components': page_components, 
        'form_factors': form_factors,
        'vendors': vendors,
        }

    return render(request, 'main/components.html', context)
```

**Additional testing to see where / why it's taking so long:**

|  | Page Components Size | Load Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| With Page Paginator | 61.9 kB | ~7 to 8 sec |
| Without Page Paginator | 1.1 MB | ~7 to 8 sec |

When using page paginator, even though I am not loading 1000+ items to the DOM it still takes 7-8 seconds for the page to load. This is on a paid heroku server too.

**Page Load Time with Page Paginator**

[image]

---

**Additional Information:**

```
class Component(models.Model):
    STATUS = (('In Production', 'In Production'), ('Retired', 'Retired'))

    # required inputs
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    component_type          = models.ForeignKey(ComponentType, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    form_factor             = models.ForeignKey(FormFactor, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    vendor                  = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    slug                    = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    # optional inputs
    heritage                = models.BooleanField(max_length=255, null=True, default="")
    status                  = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, choices=STATUS, null=True, )
    mass_dry                = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0, blank=True)
    power_average           = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0, blank=True)
    cost_min                = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0, blank=True)
    cost_max                = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0, blank=True)
    fiscal_year             = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0, blank=True)
    lead_time_min_months    = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0, blank=True)
    lead_time_max_months    = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0, blank=True)
    description             = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True)

    # files
    featured_image          = models.ImageField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to='temp/components')
    file_datasheet          = models.FileField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to='temp/components')
    file_icd                = models.FileField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to='temp/components')
    file_cad                = models.FileField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, upload_to='temp/components')

    show_component          = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=True)
    date_created            = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date_created", auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified           = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date_modified", auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("component:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        # this sets the name that is displayed in the django admin panel
        return self.name


class Vendor(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Not Active', 'Not Active'),
        ('Unknown', 'Unknown'),
    )

    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    website         = models.CharField(max_length=1020, null=True)
    contact_email   = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    contact_phone   = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True)
    year_founded    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATUS)

    date_created    = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date_created", auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified   = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date_modified", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        # this sets the name that is displayed in the django admin panel
        return self.name
```

Comment: Most likely the `order_by` as that can often be expensive. You also may want to explore using a class-based `ListView` and using Djangos built in `paginate_by' function.

Comment: @Anthony are class-based `ListView`'s less expensive? Is `order_by` still taxing/expensive if it lives in the class?